# Could itextpdf extract tabular data from a multipage, complex PDF like a IRS Form 1065? (Computer generated)

Tags: pdf, itext

Some samples I have seen can only handle simple forms like a W2 or W9.
Would the current release be able to extract the data from complex tables like this form has? [IRS Tax Form 1065](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1065.pdf)

Comment: Essentially it is a question of how much work you are prepared Invest.

Comment: Depends if by "data" you mean the information a user entered into the form or the actual text of the form...

Comment: Looking to pull the information the user entered into the form. I invested a ton of time trying to do this via OCR and it was unreliable. There are a dozen tax packages that produce tax forms that are slightly different and mapping the coordinates just didn't work. I am wondering if the same issue would apply to iText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracting information from a form using iText is done through the AcroFields object.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();
String fieldValue = acroFields.getField(fieldName);
```

You can get a Set of field names by calling this code:

```
Set<String> keys = acroFields.getFields().keySet();
```

And then iterate over the acroFields object. What you then do with the data is up to you.

Other Samples using AcroFields can be found [here](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=247) and [enter link description here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms).

It seems your document also contains XFA (XML based forms technology). You can get an XfaForm object from the AcroFields object, but from there on you're on your own to parse the XML structure.